# How to fetch data from Spark and display using Angular

Tags: javascript, java, json, angularjs, spark-java

As a beginner in Spark framework and AngularJS I was trying to build a simple REST application. However I apparently can’t retrieve data from the server and display using Angular.

I started with simple task:

```
@Data
public class Todo {

private String title = "foo";
private String description= "bar" ;
}
```

In order to display the todo in the browser I send a JSON object as a response to get request.

```
get("/tasks", (request, response) ->  {
   response.type("application/json");

   Todo todo = new Todo();
   ObjectMapper mapper =  new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
   String data = mapper.writeValueAsString(todo);
   return data;
});
```

The Angular part looks as follows:

```
(function() {
   var app = angular.module('todoapp', []);

   app.controller('TaskController', ['$http', function($http) {
       var store = this;
       store.tasks = [];

       $http.get('/tasks').success(function(data) {
           store.tasks = data;
       });
   }]);

})();
```

And the index.html :

```
<ul ng-controller="TaskController as taskCtrl">
   <li ng-repeat="task in taskCtrl.tasks">{{task.title}}, {{task.description}}</li>
</ul>
```

After running Spark and entering http://localhost:4567/tasks in the browser,it shows only JSON representation:

```
{
"title": "foo",
"description": "bar"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your Spark code you are creating a '/tasks' endpoint, which you are attempting to hit with your angular code. When you try to run this in the browser, you are just hitting your '/tasks' api endpoint which is returning the expected response. You need to create another endpoint in Spark which will serve up the appropriate HTML and JavaScript code.

Comment: else you could add a html page with the jquery in the root directory

Comment: Also correct, you need a server endpoint to pull up the html/js. If you don't want the server code to do anything but serve up the static file, you could take this approach. But I assume you will want an actual route configured in Spark which will include this html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of angular you are using but in the version I use `$http` returns a different data structure than the one you show.

So to get the data from an `$http` request I would do something like,

```
$http({
    url: '/tasks',
    method: 'get'
}).then(function(result){
    $scope.tasks = result.data;
});
```

The result.data is where the data structure on `$http` returns differ from what I see in your code.

Try `console.log(data)` to get a look at what the call is getting back.

Comment: The syntax the original poster used is a shortcut. Here is the reference in the angular docs:

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)

Comment: You bet. For what its worth I would suggest sticking to your syntax though.   Its a lot easier on the eyes if all $http calls are made using the same syntax regardless of what http method you're using.